# How to remove windows shutdown alert

Tags: windows, command-line, shutdown

I'm using the command line `shutdown -s -t xxx` to set a timer to shutdown but when its about 2 or 5min away he displays a giant blue modal alert telling me windows will shutdown.

Is it possible to remove this alert or set it to 100ms before shutdown?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for example

`timeout -t xxx -nobreak && shutdown -s -t 00`

Comment: what does -nobreak stand for, this is a setTimeout to call shutdown with 0 cooldown, yes? Is is possible to cancel like shutdown /a?

Comment: -nobreak used for ignore key pressing, with this construction shutdown /a will be not work cause shutdown command will start immediately after timeout counter